# Trimming filenames (translating from bash to Python)

Tags: python, bash

Here is the working code I have in bash:

```sh
inputDir='bla/bla/RNAseq/fastq/original/test'

for trimFile in $inputDir/*".1.trimmed"
    do
       filenumtwo=`basename -s .1.trimmed "$trimFile"`
       /bla/bla/softwares/SolexaQA++_v3.0/Linux_x64/SolexaQA++ lengthsort -l 20 -c $trimFile $inputDir/$filenumtwo.2.trimmed
    done
```

So as you can see, I am able to specifically loop for only files ending with .1.trimmed in the folder, clipping the extension and storing the result in a new variable, and use that variable and simply add .2.trimmed to it so I have those paired files as arguments.

I want to do that with python but it doesn't work. I have tried using set, defining a class, or simply using the trimFile.endswith("1.trimmed") but it doesn't work. I am missing on something simple I am sure.

Here is my latest try in python... I've gone through many different loop configurations:

```python
solexa = "/bla/bla/softwares/SolexaQA++_v3.0/Linux_x64/SolexaQA++"
clipped = "/bla/bla/RNAseq/fastq/test/clipped/"

for trimFile in os.listdir("."):
   if trimFile.endswith("1.trimmed"):
      print "Clipping with SolexaQA++"
      command = [solexa,"lengthsort","-l","20","-c",trimFile,trimFile.endswith("2.trimmed"),"-d",clipped]
      subprocess.call(command)
```

EDIT: thank you, here is what worked for me

```
for trimFile in glob.glob("*1.trimmed"):
    print "Clipping with SolexaQA++"
    trimFile2 = trimFile[:-9]
    trimFile2 = trimFile2 + '2.trimmed'
    command = [solexa,"lengthsort","-l","20","-c",trimFile,trimFile2,"-d",clipped]
    subprocess.call(command)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of files matching a certain pattern, I'd recommend using [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).  For example to find what you want, you could write this:

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob('*.1.trimmed'):
    ...
```